# Can a grounded capacitor, which was charged originally, store infinite charge?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, potential-energy, capacitance

Let us consider the following arrangement. Two infinitely long parallel plates separated by $d$. Let their cross-sectional area be A. Energy stored in a 2 two plate system upon calculation can be proved to be $$U=-\frac{QQ_od}{2A\epsilon_o}$$
Nature like to stay at low energy state. It always prefers low energy state. Now, when the plate carrying $Q$ charge is grounded, to attain the minimum possible energy ($U=-\infty) $, $Q$ should become equal to $\infty$ (assuming $Q>0$). But this doesn’t feel right. If it were some object of finite dimensions, this won’t be possible because the self energy will increase as we pump more and more charge into the object and will in turn increase the potential energy.

What exactly will happen in our case? Does the plate acquire infinite charge? [image: Two parallel plates]

The following shows steps show how I arrived at that formula.
[image: potential proof]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145930/discussion-on-question-by-amsterdam6483-can-a-grounded-capacitor-which-was-char); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a short comment earlier, your immediate issue is that your energy expression is just plain wrong. I do not know how you were able to prove something false, but it is.

Theoretically, an infinitely large plate capacitor is easiest to analyse, and we tend to approximate a finite plate capacitor as a section of the infinite case. That is how we get the famous formula for a plate capacitor:
$$C=\frac{\epsilon_0\epsilon_rA}d\qquad\bigwedge\qquad Q=CV$$
where you seem to be considering vacuum or air gap, thus $\epsilon_r=1$

The energy for a capacitor is
$$U=\frac12QV=\frac{Q^2}{2C}=\frac{Q^2d}{2A\epsilon_0}$$
Note that this is $Q^2$ and **not** $-QQ_0$ as you thought it was. In the correct expression, there is no way for a transfer of charge to/from ground to arbitrarily make the energy stored in the capacitor to be more or less than this value.

---

We can now look at some of these things in greater detail. We can express the energy alternatively as 
$$U=\frac12CV^2=\frac{\epsilon_0V^2A}{2d}
=\frac12\epsilon_0\left(\frac Vd\right)^2Ad
=\frac12\epsilon_0\left|\vec  E \right|^2Ad$$
This last expression is the most interesting and insightful version. If you derived it from the $Q^2$ version, you would see that $\left|\vec E\right|=Q/A\epsilon_0$

The reason why this last form of the energy expression is interesting, is because it says that the energy in a capacitor is stored by having the electric field between the capacitor plates. The electric field between the plates are taken to be uniform and constant, and by occupying a volume $=Ad$, this gives the energy of the capacitor. You can thus see
$$\frac U{Ad}=\frac12\epsilon_0\left|\vec E\right|^2$$
as the *energy density (per volume)* of any electric field. It is also very helpful for our analysis because, if we take that the capacitor is of infinite size, then $U\to\infty,\ Q\to\infty,\ A\to\infty$ while keeping $\frac QA=\epsilon_0\left|\vec E\right|$ and $\frac UA$ constant.

We can then study this in a few ways. Either the capacitor plates are really infinitely large, but we only consider a finite area $A$ chunk of it, and speak of the energy for that area, or equivalently we speak of the energy per unit area. This will then give us sensible results.

Or, we can consider that the capacitor plates are really of finite area $A$. Then what we are doing is a very physically nonsensical thing. We are saying that the electric field between the capacitors is a constant when within the plate area, and that suddenly drops to zero the moment you consider any tiny amount outside the plate. *This is in direct contradiction with Maxwell's equations, because there is no physical mechanism for this sharp drop in electric field.* In fact, we know that Maxwell's equations expects that the electric field right at the edge of such an area, drops to about half the field in the middle. The real field is very complicated, with an infinitely long drop off, and the field quickly rises from half the maximum field strength to almost the maximum field strength even just a little bit into the plate area. Amusingly, even though the field decreases a little, the spillage of the field outside of the capacitor means that the infinite plate approximation of the capacitance, and the energy stored formula, is actually better than it looks. The difference is observable, but is always relatively small.

Younger me really much more preferred using the potential $V$ rather than using the electric field view. However, especially when you have *bound charges* like those in the conductor that are automatically moving around, one has no choice but to revert to the integral of force on moving a test charge quasistatically from infinity inwards to define the energy, and in that case the electric field view is much more trustworthy than using blindly trusting the use of potential $V$.

---

Finally, we can talk about a rather important misconception that you are having. Let us take the infinite plate case again, and consider what happens if $Q_0$ is independent of $Q$.

Let us begin by **not** grounding any plate. If $Q\neq-Q_0$, then not only do you have an electric field between the plates
$$\left|\vec E\right|_\text{between}=\frac{\left|Q+(-Q_0)\right|}{2A\epsilon_0}$$
but that you will also have
$$\left|\vec E\right|_\text{outside}=\frac{\left|Q+Q_0\right|}{2A\epsilon_0}$$
and this will be a catastrophe because, this time, $d=\infty$, leading to infinite energy.

If you ground the left plate, then charges will flow between ground and the left plate until $Q=-Q_0$ so as to make the electric field outside the capacitor equal to zero. Obviously, by symmetry, if you ground the right plate, then $Q_0=-Q$ will happen.

If you started with the left plate grounded and changed the charge $Q_0$, charges will flow between the left plate and ground to maintain $Q=-Q_0$

The case for finite sized capacitor is the one where you can actually have $Q\neq-Q_0$, that the two plates can be charged independently. But as you saw, it can take a lot of energy to accumulate such imbalanced charges, and so it is rarely treated as a possibility. It actually would not be uniform constant electric field in this case, but rather would look like a point charge if observed from very far away, and so the energy integral will not be too singular, since the integral only diverges near the origin for a point charge, and this system will thus not have a divergence since it is not actually a point charge.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think now I understand why my question might be confusing. I never used the word capacitor. Yes, for a capacitor the potential energy is $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$. For the two plate system, if the charges were equal and opposite, the formula that I used will simplify to $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$.

Comment: I have specifically also chosen to treat the case of it being independently charged, precisely the case you were having issues with, and show that you cannot arbitrarily choose for it to be so. Either you have equal and opposite charges, or you handle the finite size properly.

Comment: Thanks, I got that. The previous comment was meant to clarify. Also, the expression that you have derived for energy density is for the region between the plates. How can we generalise it to entire space? Also I have seen people using this idea of “energy being stored in the field”. I don’t get it. Can you please suggest some material longline that might help me understand it better? It is too much to ask you to explain that.

Comment: Yes, because of the beautiful symmetry of infinite plates, you can generalise it to the entire space. I myself didn't like the idea that the energy is stored in the fields, so you might want to use a proper textbook, or search for the answers definitely already posted onto this site. You might want to first understand the simpler, definitely usable in the finite case, of $U=\frac12QV$ formula that is fundamental. But I do think you might already know this.

Comment: Taking the conversation, of deriving E field and energy U of the capacitor, over from the main question over to here, I have to say that when you take the pillbox both sides outside the plate, then you have a different E field outside both plates and in between the plates. Their contribution to the flux is thus different and you need to take that into account. As for the potential energy of a capacitor, what you are really doing is taking charge from one plate and sending to the other. The E field is thus not constant as you charge up the plates. Doing this properly is where the half appears.

Comment: I have no confusion regarding why there is a half in the first place. If you think the expression I have shared for potential energy is wrong, can you please share what you think is the right expression that would represent potential energy? Along with how you got it?

Comment: The correct expression is inside my answer. To get it, you should be doing $$U=\int_0^QV(q)\mathrm dq=\int_0^Q\frac qC\mathrm dq=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$$ *That is the true source of the half, and also why your integral for the potential energy is wrong, even if you can get the correct results under specific conditions.* As such, if you insist that the two plates have independent charges, then the energy stored between the plates (i.e. ignoring the infinite energy outside the plates) will be $$U=\frac{(Q-Q_0)^2d}{8A\epsilon_0}$$ and not what you had.